# Drupal - Show content on specific page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Am I able to add the following field to a content type, so that each piece of content I create can be conditioned to a page?

[image: specific page field]

Or is there a module to extend Publishing Options, where by it adds all the pages I have created (just like 'Promote to Front Page')?
If not, why is no one doing this? As a new user to Drupal this seems like it would be a handy operation. (I have already tried [this module](http://drupal.org/project/custom_pub) but it doesn't achieve the results I'm after).

If none of these solutions are available, what would be the best alternative way of doing this?

I've posted this question on [Stack Exchange for Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49915/show-content-on-specific-page) but I need a quick answer and there seems to be a bigger community here :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used Views? it is one of the most common used drupal modules. It doesn't extend publishing options directly but it does replace it in a way. You can say by example put a list of al content-types: your_own_Content_type that have the publishing options of promoted to front-page. then sort them by title, date, what ever you like.

you could also create only one view and create multiple blocks out of it. you have to understand the logic of drupal: if you want different blocks on different pages, you have to create the different pages AND different blocks

create the view for one type of content-type and make one block out of it. put this block on the desired page. All your other blocks are made with the same view, just adjust a condition in your view and create a new block out of it. You should also put all your blocks in the same region, and set the to the right pages

here you can find a lot of documentation if you run into any problems... [drupal.org/project/views](http://drupal.org/project/views)

Comment: I thought it was fairly clear but please refer to the comment I've left in @sisko's post. Hopefully that will make it a little clearer.

Comment: So there is no easier way of doing this? Surely it would be a lot easier if you could define what page a node appears on, then select all nodes of that content type (using views), for example, and only the ones matching the page 'slug' appear. This would allow the use of just one view.

Comment: I don't see how it would be more logical to create more than one view. Would you be able to point me in the right direction so I could alter a node before it's render, i.e. `unset()` the node before it's rendered.

Comment: Okay, I'm getting my head around to this now. How would i condition a views block on what page I'm viewing though?

Comment: None of the answers really helped solve it if I'm honest. Your comments were more helpful than anything! If you put your comments in to an answer I'd be happy to accept it, however the bounty has expired now unfortunately.

Comment: here you go, deleted my comments to avoid any confusing

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context). With Context, you'll be able to manage contextual conditions and reactions for your drupal like Regions.

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials for this, I can't seem to achieve what I've asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Views is the best at creating a slideshow of images or any type of data on your site.

Used in combination with nodequeue it might offer near or the full functionality you are trying to achieve (check [this](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode44) out ... and [this](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode20) too) - but I don't understand your question entirely.

Comment: The nodequeue looks good however it still doesn't really solve the issue I have. What would be idea would be to select all nodes of a certain type in a view then, depending on what page is being viewed, only a certain view out off all the nodes in the view are shown.

Answer (score 0):

By my opinion Views is too complicated task for much simple request.

There is a few ideas for solution:

1. **Easy way** - You can create a specific template file or add some if statments to the node.tpl.php(specific tpl better)
2. **For minor changes** - Create a new [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) with "path" filter and "theme html" reaction, than hide the field by the css
3. **Best but complicated(large usages)** - create a new ["view mode"](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7) and implement the display by new ["hook_menu"](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

~ Almog